# Android WebView is calling onActivityStopped method on App Class

Tags: android, webview, background

I need to do an API request to let a service know when the app goes to background.

The problem is when I open an activity that contains a WebView inside.

I don't know why when this activity is opened the `onActivityStopped()` from the App class is called, so I have this:

**App.kt**

```
class App: Application() {
    override fun onCreate(){
        super.onCreate()
        ....
        // some logic here
        ....
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(AppLifecycleTracker())
}

    inner class AppLifecyclerTracker: ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
        override fun onActivityStopped(Activity: Activity){
            // some logic here
        }
    }

}
```

so, if in the `MainActivity.kt` I call the `WebViewActivity.kt`, that onActivityStopped method will be called and I want to that method be called when the app goes to background only

btw everything works like a charm in the others classes that do not contain WebView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `MainActivity` starts any activity, `MainActivity` will be stopped. I would expect `onActivityStopped()` to be called, with your `MainActivity` instance as a parameter, to reflect this lifecycle event.

> I want to that method be called when the app goes to background only

[Use `ProcessLifecycleOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner) to determine when your app's UI moves to the background.